# CFToken cookie disappears when enabling "Use UUID for cftoken"

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I've noticed that when enabling the option "*Use UUID for cftoken*" in ColdFusion Administrator the `CFToken` cookie is no longer set in the browser.

From my understanding this option should only cause the `CFToken` cookie to be a longer alphanumeric string for security purposes.

Is there another option that might cause this behavior in conjunction with the "*Use UUID for cftoken*" option?

*Version: ColdFusion 2016*

Comment: I've had "Use UUID for cftoken" turned on for my CF 9, 10, and 11 servers and never seen an issue like you're having.
Do you have "Secure Cookie" turned on in "Memory Variables"? If it's turned on and you access the site over HTTP, then the cookies _won't_ be set.

Comment: I do not have the option "Secure Cookie" turned on, however I realize that I'm access this website internally through an IP address with `https` pre-pended. I wonder if that could cause issues when setting the cftoken cookie.

Comment: Does this test show you the cftoken? `<cfdump var="#session#">`